# Error: reached the recursion limit while instantiating `func::<[closure]>`

Tags: rust, closures

I am trying to test if a binary search tree is valid:

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

pub struct TreeNode {
    val: i32,
    left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

pub fn is_valid_bst(root: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> bool {
    preorder_traverse(root.as_ref(), |_| true)
}

fn preorder_traverse<F: Fn(i32) -> bool>(root: Option<&Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, predict: F) -> bool {
    if let Some(node) = root {
        let root_val = root.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().val;
        if !predict(root_val) {
            return false;
        }
        preorder_traverse(node.borrow().left.as_ref(), |v| v < root_val)
            && preorder_traverse(node.borrow().right.as_ref(), |v| v > root_val)
    } else {
        true
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=3479b2ffde9eac1c64c934ba30362142)):

This code triggers the following error message and that seems non-sense to me:

```
error: reached the recursion limit while instantiating `preorder_traverse::<[closure@src/lib.rs:19:56: 19:72 root_val:&i32]>`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:1
   |
13 | / fn preorder_traverse<F: Fn(i32) -> bool>(root: Option<&Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, predict: F) -> bool {
14 | |     if let Some(node) = root {
15 | |         let root_val = root.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().val;
16 | |         if !predict(root_val) {
...  |
23 | |     }
24 | | }
   | |_^
```

I've found [a potentially related Rust issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43520), but it seems outdated and I cannot understand the quoted message in the original issue well.

- What hit the recursion limit?
- How can I work around this if I want to encapsulate the predication logic in a closure or something else?

The **algorithm** to validate binary search tree in this code is not correct, but I still think the original code **should compile**.

Comment: [Super minimal example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=88c1604fe205e3c34e23fb3401612a6e). This indeed just looks like a bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Lukas Kalbertodt provides a simpler example, which I'll use as a basis for the explanation:

```
fn foo<F: Fn()>(x: bool, _: F) {
    if x {
        foo(false, || {}) // line 3
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo(true, || {}); // line 8
}
```

The important point here is that each closure has a unique type, so let's instantiate this program:

- 1st closure, in `main`, let's name the type `main#8`.
- 1st instantiation of `foo`, in `main`, `foo<[main#8]>`.
- 2nd closure, in `foo`, let's name the type `{foo<[main#8]>}#3`.
- 2nd instantiation of `foo`, in `foo`, `foo<[{foo<[main#8]>}#3]>`.
- 3rd closure, in `foo`, let's name type `{foo<[{foo<[main#8]>}#3]>}#3`.
- 3rd instantiation of `foo`, in `foo`, `foo<[{foo<[{foo<[main#8]>}#3]>}#3]>`.
- ...

Each new instantiation of `foo` creates a new closure type, each new closure type creates a new instantiation of `foo`, this is a recursion without a base case: **stack overflow**.

---

You can solve the problem by NOT creating a closure when recursively calling `preorder_traverse`:

- either using type erasure, although there's a runtime overhead,
- or simply by using a separate inner function for recursion, since it's independent of `F`.

Example:

```
fn preorder_traverse_impl(
    root: Option<&Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    parent_value: i32,
    predict: fn(i32, i32) -> bool
)
    -> bool
{
    if let Some(node) = root {
        let root_val = root.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().val;
        if !predict(root_val, parent_value) {
            return false;
        }
        preorder_traverse_impl(node.borrow().left.as_ref(), root_val, lessThan)
            && preorder_traverse_impl(node.borrow().right.as_ref(), root_val, greaterThan)
    } else {
        true
    }
}

fn preorder_traverse<F: Fn(i32) -> bool>(root: Option<&Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>, predict: F) -> bool {
    if let Some(node) = root {
        let root_val = root.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().val;
        if !predict(root_val) {
            return false;
        }
        preorder_traverse_impl(node.borrow().left.as_ref(), root_val, lessThan)
            && preorder_traverse_impl(node.borrow().right.as_ref(), root_val, greaterThan)
    } else {
        true
    }
}
```

On nightly you could also create a predicate type and implement `Fn` for it (`LessThan<i32>` and `GreaterThan<i32>`).

Comment: Very interesting! I completely forgot that a closure can depend on the generic parameters of the outer function. E.g. we could make the recursive call like `foo(false, || println!("{}", mem::size_of::<F>()))` which makes it very obvious that this is a problem.

Comment: Note that this can also be solved using runtime typing, so you don't have this exploding generic.

`fn preorder_traverse(..., predict: Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> bool>) -> bool`

Answer (score 2):

A workaround which I have not seen discussed yet is this:

Define your own trait, then pass in one or the other struct which implements it. For example:

```rust
trait Comparison { fn compare(v: T, root: T) -> bool }

struct LessThan;
struct GreaterThan;

impl Comparison for LessThan {
  fn compare(v: T, root: T) -> bool { v < root }
}

impl Comparison for GreaterThan {
  fn compare(v: T, root: T) -> bool { v > root }
}
```

In your case this seems like overkill, since an `fn` type will do. However, in cases where you *do* want to close over something, you can add fields to your struct and then use those fields in the method.

That way—since the struct types do not depend (on the type level) on the place you instantiate them—the type-level recursion limit will not be hit.