# Recursion limit when instantiating (unused?) Rust type

Tags: rust

I implemented [worstsort](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/papers/inefficient_algorithms.pdf) in Rust:

```
fn bubblesort<T: PartialOrd>(l: &mut [T]) {
    for i in 1..l.len() {
        for j in 0..l.len() - i {
            if l[j + 1] < l[j] {
                l.swap(j + 1, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

fn permutations<T: Clone>(l: &[T]) -> Vec<Vec<T>> {
    if l.len() <= 1 {
        return vec![l.to_vec()];
    }

    let mut res = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..l.len() {
        let mut lcopy = l.to_vec();
        lcopy.remove(i);
        let p = permutations(&lcopy);
        for perm in p {
            let mut fullperm = vec![l[i].clone()];
            fullperm.extend(perm);
            res.push(fullperm);
        }
    }
    res
}

pub fn badsort<T: PartialOrd + Clone>(k: usize, l: &mut [T]) {
    if k == 0 {
        bubblesort(l);
    } else {
        let mut p = permutations(l);
        badsort(k - 1, &mut p);
        l.clone_from_slice(&p[0]);
    }
}

pub fn worstsort<T, F>(l: &mut [T], f: F)
where
    T: PartialOrd + Clone,
    F: FnOnce(usize) -> usize,
{
    badsort(f(l.len()), l);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn badsort_zero() {
        let mut unsorted = vec![8, 3, 5];
        badsort(0, &mut unsorted);
        assert_eq!(unsorted, vec![3, 5, 8]);
    }
    #[test]
    fn worstsort_id() {
        let mut unsorted = vec![8, 3, 5];
        worstsort(&mut unsorted, |n| n);
        assert_eq!(unsorted, vec![3, 5, 8]);
    }
}
```

It compiles and checks fine, until I tried to write tests that actually calling the `worstsort` and `badsort` functions, and `cargo test` gives an error:

```
error: reached the recursion limit while instantiating `badsort::<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<i32>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`
```

I get this error even when calling `badsort(0, l)`, which should just be bubblesort, with no recursive calls whatsoever. My assumption is that rustc is trying to generate monomorphised versions of `badsort` for every possible `usize` (I swapped the type to `u8` and got the same error), but I don't understand why: it errors whatever the argument is, even when it doesn't recursively call itself at all!  I tried setting the recursion limit all the way up to `#![recursion_limit="1024"]`, but it still hits this limit and fails, even with `u8`.

Is my guess correct? Is there a way to get this (admittedly perverse) code to compile and run at all?

Comment: `badsort` calls itself on a `Vec<Vec<T>>`, which is going to call itself on a `Vec<Vec<Vec<Vec<T>>>>` which is going to call itself etc etc

Comment: @mcarton Yes, obviously we're going to hit recursion limits pretty fast once the list is non-trivial. I suppose the compiler isn't smart enough (or isn't smart enough early enough) to figure out that if we never call `badsort` with `k` larger than some small value, it doesn't need to generate that many type specialisations.

Comment: That's not how static typing works, the compiler doesn't care about the value of the parameter `k` to resolve the types in your function.

Comment: Somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54617718/147192 => static typing doesn't care about "which branch", first the types must line up, and here you have infinite types/functions being instantiated.

Comment: Ah right, of course. I originally saw this implemented in Haskell, where it works fine, hence my confusion on why this might be something to do with the monomorphisation. I suppose more consideration and thought is required: an interesting learning opportunity!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are recursive struct types illegal in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296195/why-are-recursive-struct-types-illegal-in-rust)